# Help identify a game with a vampire and his servants

Tags: identify-this-game

A friend asked me quite a question yesterday. She was trying to remember a game that she saw in a game shop when she was a child, in the 80s-90s. On its cover was a vampire at a table, ready to eat, with two servants bringing plates and one trying to trip the other.

I guess by the description of the box that each player tries to bring the vampire's food first, or perhaps as many times as possible, and prevent other players from doing so.

Can anyone help identify this game?

Comment: Maybe she could try to identify the cover on http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/6428/vampires

Comment: Inevitability, these sorts of questions become discussions and help one person. Clairification is needed to determine in what language the game was released, was it really the cover, did they get the details right, and soon you arrive at a game [completely different](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/469/in-teufels-kuche) than the initial description.